# Why the value of a variable does not change when using initState in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to obtain the value of `groupfav` that is stored in FireStore to pass it as part of the reference to a `Stream`, but even when in `initState` I obtain the corresponding value, the original variable is not changed to the new value, therefore it does not load the list corresponding to the value obtained, I tried many solutions and ideas, but I can't make the String groupfav change to the new value.

```
static String? userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  static final userColeccion =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  String groupfav = ' '; //this value should be replaced by the future value obtained
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> task;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    userColeccion.doc("$userID").get().then((value) {
      groupfav = value.data()!["groupfav"];
      print(groupfav); //correctly prints the value I want (is "groupid4")
      return groupfav;
    });

    taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
        .collection("task")
        .snapshots();
  }
```

doing all this should replace `String groupfav = ' ';` to `String groupfav = 'groupid4'`, but it doesn't work, it stays at ' ', thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a synchronous call by attaching a callback to the **usersCollection.get()** call. It is only inside the **.then** that the asynchronous call gets fulfilled. This call does not wait and it just continues right through to the next call, which is fetching the **FirebaseFiresstore.instance**, by then the value is still empty for the **groupfav**. What you need to do is nest that call inside the **.then()**, because it is then (pun intended!) when the value will be set because of how asynchronous calls work when using the **.then** chain of events, so do it like this:

```dart
userColeccion.doc("$userID").get().then((value) {
      groupfav = value.data()!["groupfav"];
      print(groupfav); //correctly prints the value I want (is "groupid4")
      
      // right inside the **.then, after getting the value
      // THEN you can fetch the document with name 'groupfav'
      // from your collection
      taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
        .collection("task")
        .snapshots();

});
```

Unfortunately you cannot make the **initState** asynchronous (decorating it with the **async** keyword), otherwise I would've suggested using the **await** instead of the **.then**. Another way would be to take all these oeprations into a separate method which indeed waits for the call on the **usersCollection**, as in:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getGroupFavData();
}

void getGroupFavData() async {

  var groupFavData = await userColeccion.doc("$userID").get();
  var groupfav = groupFavData.data()!['groupfav'];

  taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("groups")
    .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
    .collection("task")
    .snapshots();

}
```

Comment: thanks actually cleared things up a lot for me, but I get an error `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'taskGroup' has not been initialized.)` I tried to fix it by doing `Stream<QuerySnapshot>? task;` in `late Stream<QuerySnapshot> task;`, but it led me to another error `StateError (Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error)`, if everything is inside a class that extends StatefulWidget

Comment: Yeah you could define it outside (i assumed you already had it defined). You're returning the snapshots out of that collection, so I'm assuming you'll be listening on that stream. You can either: 1) feed the snapshots straight into a StreamBuilder 2) call the **listen** on the snapshots, which will allow you hook up a handler, in which you can consume the stream. Let me know what else you need so we can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I added more code and that same one gives me "Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error)", I don't understand what it is due to, I tried to solve it with the comment above but nothing, mainly I am feeding a streambuilder with `taskGroup`

Comment: I can help you with your next issue, no problem - but I believe we addressed the initial question which was why the variable wasn't changing (stated in the issue's title). Can you confirm that it is changing now? I'd be glad to help you solve now the Streaming issue, once you closing this one, marking it correct and opening up another issue. Hope you don't mind, since the streaming issue has nothing to do with the 'groupfav' issue. I'll be on the lookout.

Comment: Technically I do not know if the value is really being passed, but I understand and accept what you say, I have created one with the following question, thanks.

Comment: Great. I'll help you figure out your snapshot issue now. Thanks!